# How to use deletedPkQuery

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a data-config.xml with 2 entity, like

```
<entity name="full" PK="ID" ...>
...
</entity>
```

and

```
<entity name="delta_build" PK="ID" ...>
...
</entity>
```

entity delta_build is for delta import, query is

```
?command=full-import&entity=delta_build&clean=false
```

and I want to using deletedPkQuery to delete index. So I have add those to entity "delta_build"

```
deltaQuery="select -1 as ID from dual"

deltaImportQuery="select * from product where a.id='${dataimporter.delta.ID}' "

deletedPKQuery="select product_id as ID from modified_product where gmt_create &gt; to_date('${dataimporter.last_index_time}','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and modification = 'deleted'"
```

deltaQuery and deltaImportQuery is simply to avoid delta import any records, course delta import has been implement by full import. and I am just want using delta for delete index.

But when I hit query

```
?command=delta-import
```

deltaQuery and deltaImportQuery can be found in log, and without deletedPKQuery. Is there any thing wrong in config file?

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons straight away.
1. use '${dataimporter.delta.product_id}' instead of '${dataimporter.delta.ID}'
2. Use deletedPkQuery instead of deletedPKQuery.